# Onsen Ui res folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, onsen-ui, apache-cordova

Using Visual studio with Blank app (apache cordova) template i can to find the path : res\native\android  and the file ant.properties.

But, where is the same path/file on Onsen Ui  template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Onsen templates you can not find a res  folder, but you can create a res folder to the project. res folder is relative to the **project directory** and **not to** the **www directory**.